# Finding Average of Times with HR:MIN in R

Tags: r, time

I am trying to find the average time of the dataset below in R

```
c("1:00", "12:45", "12:45", "1:00", "7:30", "12:45", "7:15", 
"8:00", "12:30", "12:15", "12:45", "7:30", "7:45", "12:45", "11:30", 
"11:00", "10:45", "10:30", "4:30", "11:00", "11:00", "9:45", 
"9:45", "11:00", "11:15", "4:45", "11:15", "11:15", "11:00", 
"11:00", "2:15", "10:45", "10:45", "11:00", "11:30", "10:30", 
"11:00", "11:15", "10:45", "12:45", "1:15", "12:45", "7:45", 
"1:00", "1:15", "12:45", "1:00", "8:00", "1:15", "12:15", "11:00", 
"11:15", "5:00", "11:00", "10:45", "11:00", "11:30", "11:00", 
"5:00", "10:45", "11:00", "2:30", "10:45", "11:15", "11:15", 
"10:15", "11:00", "11:00", "11:00", "11:15", "11:15", "11:15", 
"11:00", "11:00", "2:30", "10:30", "10:30", "5:15", "10:15", 
"10:45", "11:15", "11:00", "11:15", "10:00", "12:30", "12:15", 
"12:45", "1:00", "8:15", "1:00", "7:30", "12:45", "12:30", "12:45", 
"12:30", "12:30", "1:00", "8:00", "12:15", "12:30")
```

Keeping in the same format

FWIW they are all currently 'character' class

This one particularly, with the answers provided produce 5:24

```
c("1:00", "1:45", "1:00", "12:45", "1:30", "1:00", "1:30", "1:45", 
"1:45", "12:45", "1:00", "12:45", "1:30", "1:15", "12:30", "12:30", 
"12:45", "1:00", "1:15", "1:15", "1:15", "12:30", "12:45", "1:15", 
"12:45", "1:00", "1:30", "1:15", "12:45", "12:45", "12:30")
```

Comment: With package `chron` you can compute `mean(chron::as.times(paste0(times, ":00")))`. Then remove or round the seconds.

Answer (score 2):

In `base R` you can use this:

```
format(mean(strptime(times, "%H:%M")), "%H:%M")
```

Output:

```
[1] "09:24"
```

Comment: Much. simpler than  mine, upvote. But `format` truncates the mean time, the following rounds it: `mean_time <- mean(strptime(times, "%H:%M")); round(mean_time, unit = "mins")`. Then format with `"%H:%M"`.

Comment: The problem I'm facing with these solutions is when dealing with times centralized around 12:00 - 1:00 they produce an average at around 5:30 for some reason. I'll add the data frame that's doing that to the original post

Comment: Hi @JacksonDels, what is your expected output instead of 5:30?

Comment: @JacksonDels If you say you have times around 12:00 - 1:00, those now seem to be 1:00 *PM* or 1:00 *of the next day*. Is it so and if yes, which of these case is right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

1. Coerce the character strings vector to package `chron` S3 class `"time"`;
2. compute the mean times with the method `mean` for this class;
3. round to minutes;
4. remove the seconds digits.

```r
times <- c("1:00", "12:45", "12:45", "1:00", "7:30", "12:45", "7:15", 
           "8:00", "12:30", "12:15", "12:45", "7:30", "7:45", "12:45", "11:30", 
           "11:00", "10:45", "10:30", "4:30", "11:00", "11:00", "9:45", 
           "9:45", "11:00", "11:15", "4:45", "11:15", "11:15", "11:00", 
           "11:00", "2:15", "10:45", "10:45", "11:00", "11:30", "10:30", 
           "11:00", "11:15", "10:45", "12:45", "1:15", "12:45", "7:45", 
           "1:00", "1:15", "12:45", "1:00", "8:00", "1:15", "12:15", "11:00", 
           "11:15", "5:00", "11:00", "10:45", "11:00", "11:30", "11:00", 
           "5:00", "10:45", "11:00", "2:30", "10:45", "11:15", "11:15", 
           "10:15", "11:00", "11:00", "11:00", "11:15", "11:15", "11:15", 
           "11:00", "11:00", "2:30", "10:30", "10:30", "5:15", "10:15", 
           "10:45", "11:15", "11:00", "11:15", "10:00", "12:30", "12:15", 
           "12:45", "1:00", "8:15", "1:00", "7:30", "12:45", "12:30", "12:45", 
           "12:30", "12:30", "1:00", "8:00", "12:15", "12:30")

library(chron)

times <- as.times(paste0(times, ":00"))
mean(times)
#> [1] 09:24:27

mean_time <- round(mean(times), unit = "minutes")
mean_time
#> [1] 09:24:00

mean_time <- sub(":\\d{2}$", "",mean_time)
mean_time
#> [1] "09:24"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried doing so, but when inputting the following data set c("1:00", "1:45", "1:00", "12:45", "1:30", "1:00", "1:30", "1:45", 
"1:45", "12:45", "1:00", "12:45", "1:30", "1:15", "12:30", "12:30", 
"12:45", "1:00", "1:15", "1:15", "1:15", "12:30", "12:45", "1:15", 
"12:45", "1:00", "1:30", "1:15", "12:45", "12:45", "12:30") it gives me around 5:42 which is inaccurate

Comment: @JacksonDels Why do you say it's inaccurate? When I plot the vector's histogram, 5:42 is right between the two bars. Though irrelevant, the median is 01:30. What you have is a skewed distribution of times.